# Difference between document activities and regular activities

Tags: android, android-activity

When I read the end of the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents#retain-finished), I found the sentence which says,

> The default value is true for document activities, and false for
> regular activities.

Could someone explain what's the difference between the both ? By default we touch the Back button to destroy an Activity, we still can see the task on the Recents Screen. So I guess it belongs to regular activities. But how about the document activities ? Could you take some examples which belong to them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good explanation of document activities can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents

It is normal, even if you don't have a "Document Activity", for your app to show up in the list of recent tasks after you use the BACK button to finish it. The app is not running, but the list of recent tasks shows all running tasks and also a number of tasks that were recently used.

Document activities allow multiple instances of the same `Activity` to exist in different tasks, and therefore there will be multiple instances of the same app (with different documents) in the list of recent tasks.

Personally I think this concept is confusing for the user, but...

Comment: So I guess if I start a FooActivity through an intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT`.  It'll belong to Document Activity. Then if I click back button to finish the FooActivity. It won't be shown on Recents Screen by default without setting the attribute `android:autoRemoveFromRecents`. I'll do some tests for verifying this. 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's correct, but you shouldn't use the document mechanism if your app is not document-centric. Most apps are not document-centric. You will confuse users if you use the document mechanism if your app is not document-centric. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: If you just don't want your app to show up in the list of recent tasks, there are easier/better ways to do that.

Comment: Actually I just studied the official guide and got confused by the context ^^".